# How to fix invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x13) was found in the element content of the document

Tags: java, pdf

I have some strange character in my content that needs to be convert to PDF.

[image]

When try to convert to pdf I receive this error:

```
    >>> Creation of PDF {} is invalid!
Can't load the XML resource (using TRaX transformer). org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 20; columnNumber: 4615; An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x13) was found in the element content of the document.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 20; columnNumber: 4615; An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x13) was found in the element content of the document.
An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x13) was found in the element content of the document.
```

Here is code example:

```
    public ByteArrayInputStream createPdf(String textToConvert) throws IOException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();

    try {
        PdfRendererBuilder builder = new PdfRendererBuilder();
        builder.defaultTextDirection(BaseRendererBuilder.TextDirection.LTR);

        builder.withHtmlContent(textToConvert, "");

        PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(document, this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("fonts/" + FontNameEnum.TT_NORMS_PRO_REGULAR.getName()));
        font.encode("UTF-8");
        PDFontSupplier fontSupplier = new PDFontSupplier(font);

        builder.useFont(fontSupplier, "TTNormsPro-Regular");
        builder.usePDDocument(document);

        PdfBoxRenderer renderer = builder.buildPdfRenderer();
        renderer.createPDFWithoutClosing();

        document.save(out);
    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printstackTrace();
    } finally {
        document.close();
    }

    return new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
}
```

String that is passing into the method is htmlContent, but this strange Unicode character is making me problem.
I tried to remove it with \P{Print}, but it also removes UTF-8 characters like Ÿ, Ã, È

Comment: @KJ you think this 0x13 is some carriage return?

Comment: If it is just this one character you can just remove it like textToConvert.replace("\u0013", "");

Comment: @Mar-Z is there some regex where I can remove all possible invalid XML characters?